# How to use corrcoef function for between subject design

Tags: matlab, statistics, correlation

I have 150 participants and I need to divide them in terms of healthy vs unhealthy. Healthy subjects means non-smoker and do not have any diagnosed mental disorders. I have two different data to decide whether they are healthy or not.

```
%B.disorder 0= does not have any disoroder  1= have at least one disorder
%B.smoke 0= non-smoker 1= smoker

healthypart= sum(Info.mentalhealth,2)+sum(Info.smoking,2);

healthysubs(healthysubs~=0)= 5;
healthysubs(healthysubs==0)= 1;      % 1 = healthy
healthysubs(healthysubs==5)= 0; % unhealthy subjects(smoker, diagnosed w md)
```

I need to draw correlation tables for both 'all subjects' and 'healthy subjects'. That's why I need to create variable for all subjects. I did this with the following line.

```
allsubs=ones(150,1);
```

I use corrcoef with these lines;

```
X = [cell2mat(Info.reactionTimes), healthysubs,allsubs];

[R, P] = corrcoef(X, 'rows', 'pairwise');
```

And here are my results;

```
R =

   1.0000   -0.0142       NaN
   -0.0142    1.0000       NaN
    NaN       NaN       NaN


P =

1.0000    0.8883       NaN
0.8883    1.0000       NaN
   NaN       NaN       NaN
```

I think this is caused because of my healthy subjects variable. When I put another variable rather than it, I do not get any NaN values. So how can I use corrcoef for both my healthy subjects and all subjects? Is there a way to create an all subjects vairable?

```
Info.mentalhealth=            

 1                      
 1               
 0
 1                
...               
 1                
 1                 
 0                    
 1                   
 0                 
 0
 0                    
 0                     
 0                        


  Info.smoking=  

 0
 0
 1
 1
 1
 0
 1
...
 1
 0
 0
 1
 1
 1
 1
 0
```

These are my data for smokers and disorders, 1 means that participant has a disorder or a smoker. They are two different values. Each row represents a participant.

Comment: Hard to tell, if we don't have a data sample.

Comment: @TommasoBelluzzoI have 150 participants, and I did generate the healthy subjects variable with  `healthysubs= sum(B.disorder,2)+sum(B.smoke,2);

healthysubs(healthysubs~=0)= 5;
healthysubs(healthysubs==0)= 1;      % 1 = healthy
healthysubs(healthysubs==5)= 0; % unhealthy subjects(smoker, disorder)` with these lines. I need to generate a similar variable for healthy subjects but when I use ones(150,1) or zeros(150,1) it gives me NaN for corrcoef results.

Comment: I was trying to tell you that your code lacks reproductibility. I know what you did on those variables... you pasted that part of code in your question too...

Comment: @TommasoBelluzzo I have 150 participant, I can divide them as healthy vs unhealhty but I cannot get a variable that represents the whole participants. My smoker and disorder variables are (150,1) too.

Comment: Can you show me some numbers? I don't know... like a 20x1 matrix of participants so I can see how your data look like.

Comment: @TommasoBelluzzo I have edited my question and added some numbers

Comment: Aaaaaaah great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `allsubs` logic you are introducing in your analysis doesn't make sense on a statistical point of view. You are trying to compute the correlation coefficient between a variable and, well, the sample population. But the value of `allsubs` is meaningless because it's a vector of ones with null variance and unit mean.

This is the function that is internally called by `corrcoef` and that is in charge of calculation the coefficients:

```
function [r,n] = correl(x)
%CORREL Compute correlation matrix without error checking.

[n,m] = size(x);
r = cov(x);
d = sqrt(diag(r)); % sqrt first to avoid under/overflow
r = r ./ d ./ d'; % r = r ./ d*d';
% Fix up possible round-off problems, while preserving NaN: put exact 1 on the
% diagonal, and limit off-diag to [-1,1].
r = (r+r')/2;
t = find(abs(r) > 1); r(t) = r(t)./abs(r(t));
r(1:m+1:end) = sign(diag(r));
```

On a technical point of view, the `cov` function returns `0` in correspondence of the row and column values related to `allsubs`. Thus, dividing `0` by `0` yields `NaN`. Using `pairwise` computation doesn't solve the problem because if the matrix doesn't contain `NaN` values, a fallback check runs the computation exactly as if you used `all` instead.

If you want to perform this analysis correctly, you have to split the operation in two distinct ones. In the first one you calculate the correlation coefficient between `disorder` and `healthysubs`, in the second you calculate the correlation coefficient between `disorder` and `unhealthysubs`:

```
disorder = [1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1].';
smoke = [0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0].';

healthysubs = (sum(disorder,2) + sum(smoke,2)) == 0;
unhealthysubs = ~healthysubs;

[R_healthy,P_healthy] = corr(disorder,healthysubs)
[R_unhealthy,P_unhealthy] = corr(disorder,unhealthysubs)
```

The result is:

```
R_healthy = -0.419313934688767
P_healthy = 0.119747441953059

R_unhealthy = 0.419313934688767
P_unhealthy = 0.119747441953059
```

Of course, as you can notice, while the p-value shows always the same significance... the correlation coefficient between `disorder` and unhealthy subs goes in the opposite direction of the correlation coefficient between `disorder` and healthy subs. So you may also want to compute only one of them and invert the sign to obtain the other.

Comment: @TommasoBelluzo I am a newbie in Matlab, and I realized I am learning with your help! Thank you very much again!